# NodeJS Promise Chaining: reuse "then" and merge two promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, method-chaining

I have 2 promises with same "then" and "catch" conditions. How can I merge them into single promise based on a condition?

**Promise 1**

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    abc.getDataFromServer(resp1)
        .then((result) => {
            .....
            resolve();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            .....
            reject(error);
        });
});
```

**Promise 2**

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    abc.getDataFromDB(resp2)
        .then((result) => {
            .....
            resolve();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            .....
            reject(error);
        });
});
```

**Required Promise Chaining**

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(condition){
       abc.getDataFromServer(resp)
    }else{
       abc.getDataFromDB(resp2)
    }
        .then((result) => {
            .....
            resolve();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            .....
            reject(error);
        });
});
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the conditional operator, based on the `condition`, to determine the initial `Promise`, and then call `.then` and `.catch` on it. Also, avoid the [explicit Promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it):

```
return (condition ? abc.getDataFromServer(resp) : abc.getDataFromDB(resp2))
  .then((result) => {
      .....
      // instead of resolve(someTransformedResult):
      return someTransformedResult;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      .....
      // instead of reject(error):
      throw error;
  });
```

Comment: if I can't avoid explicit Promise construction, then?

Comment: You *can* avoid it, given the code in your question, because you can already call `.then` directly on the Promises returned by `getDataFromServer` / `getDataFromDB`. They're thenables, so you don't need to construct a separate Promise to handle them.